# JXBrowser, How do you change the default image viewer used?

Tags: browser, preferences, jxbrowser

I'm using Ignition HMI application and it uses the JXBrowser as it's web browser component.  I need to change the default image viewer used by JXBrowser to use a web-enabled browser with more capabilities (pan & zoom,  called OpenSeaDragon).
How can that be done?   I know you can get the BrowserPreferences, but I did not see anything specific to the default apps used.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSeadragon is a JavaScript library that must be embedded into the web page and configured to provide an image viewer that can be used for panning, zooming, etc. I see they also provide a browser extension that allows you to view any image on a web page with their viewer, however, JxBrowser does not support Chrome/Chromium extensions at the moment.